# how to create several regions in a networkx graph based on a criterion

Tags: networkx

I have 02 questions:
1- From the graph2 below, I want to create several regions in a networkx based on a criterion (first zone starts at node X up to a given set of nodes). For example, region 1 starts from node 1 to nodes (4 and 16). Is there a way to do that?

[create regions on the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNpyk.png)
2- I also want to determine the depth of each node in the attached graph

[node_depth of a graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kqSV.png)

Thank you for any hint that could help.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by depth of a node in a graph? Distance from a "root" node?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "regions"? Are you asking how to create subgraphs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory_terms#subgraph)?  That is, do you want to create separate, smaller graphs which contain only the nodes and edges existing in the regions you have drawn in your picture?

If so, you can do that using the `subgraph()` function of `networkx`.
In your example, to create the subgraph of region 1 you would do:
`region1 = graph2.subgraph([1,2,3,4,11,12,13,14,15,16])`
and an equivalent statement for regions 2 and 3.

Then for node depth, I am not sure what you mean but I think you might mean distance from some root node.
Let's assume your root node is 1. 
Then to find the "depth" of each node, you want to find the distance(number of edges) between that node and 1.

To do that you could do something like:

```
for n in myGraph.nodes():
    print n, networkx.shortest_path(graph, 1, n)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedbacks. In my case, the creation of the regions is supposed to be  automatic (not manual) because when I add or remove a node it should be taken into account by the region. So the definition of the region 1 (see previous attached picture) for example is based on a simple criteria which is : the region 1 includes all the nodes from node 1 to a nodes (X,Y,..) if it is a tree-like structure with many bifurcations.

Comment: Concerning the node depth, the idea is to see how far is a node x relatively to the network backbone : is node x at 1 or 2 or 3 or n steps under the main backbone? Thanks

Comment: Your definition of region is still very unclear. Is it a subgraph? Is it just a list of nodes? Is it a coloring? What exactly do you mean by "Create regions". Secondly, your clarification of what a region is is apparently contradictory. You say a region 1 includes nodes from node 1 to (X, Y). What does this mean? Are you saying that nodes X and Y are leaf nodes? Is it always two nodes? What do you mean by FROM node 1 TO nodes(X, Y)? Do you mean that you want to include all the nodes on the shortest paths (1, X) and (1, Y)?

Comment: What do you mean by "main backbone"?  As far as I know, the terms "region" and "backbone" are not generally used terms in network science or graph theory. If you are going to use your own or your professor's terms for things, you need to very clearly define them before you use them or it is very hard to help you.

Comment: Hi, I'm not an expert in networkx so sorry for not using the right terms. Coming back to my 02 points:

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in networkx so sorry for not using the right terms. Coming back to my 02 points: A region can effectively be considered as a subgraph. To note that the main criterion behind the construction of the region is to start from a reference node (node 1 for region 1) and include all the nodes and edges until a specific condition is met on a specific edge (in my case it is the presence of a electric device on an edge).

[how to build a region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShK7J.png)